# Error in AWS Lambda function while reading from S3

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to read an excel file from S3 bucket. Here is my Lambda function code but it throws syntax error for any statement after I read the byte stream into a dataframe using `pd.read_excel`.

I am unable to figure out the issue as syntax looks fine to me. Is there an issue with reading the data? Kindly help.

```
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
    
    if event:
        
        s3_records = event["Records"][0]
        bucket_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        file_name = str(s3_records["s3"]["object"]["key"])
        
        file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
        file_content = file_obj["Body"].read()
        
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_content, engine='xlrd')
          
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Here is the log:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 23)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 23
        return {
```

Comment: are you sure ,do you have access to temp directory ?

Comment: even if i remove the writing to temp directory, it gives error on return statement. I modified the original post to show that error. Basically, any statement following the read gives syntax error. I am sure its something silly that I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing closing parenthesis just before the `return` statement, it should be this:

```js
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_content, engine='xlrd'))
```

instead of this

```js
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_content, engine='xlrd')
```